# Programming binary tree deletion without transform. tree changed after returned from the function

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

I try to delete a node from a binary search tree without transforming it. I wrote this code to delete nodes with one or none child first. when I print the result tree within the function it seems correct. But when I call the function later and try to print the tree, the tree changed. How did it happen and how can I fix the problem?

So Here is the Node:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
```

Here's how I search for the previous node of the targeted node with num data.

```
struct node * presearch(int num, struct node *p)
{
    struct node *n;
    struct node *m;
    m=p;
    if(num>m->data){n=m->right;}
    if(num<m->data){n=m->left;}
    while(n){
        if(num>n->data&&n->right!=NULL){
            m=n;
            n=n->right;
        }
        if(num<n->data&&n->left!=NULL){
            m=n;
            n=n->left;
        }
        if(num >n->data&&n->right==NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        if(num <n->data&&n->left==NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        if(num==n->data){
            break;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

This is the Deletion function:

```
struct node * delete(int num,struct node * p,struct node * n)
{
    struct node *origin;
    origin=n;
    if(p==NULL){printf("%s\n","fail" );}
    struct node * root;
    root=p;
    if (root == NULL) {return p;}
    if (num < root->data)
        root->left = delete(num,root->left,n);
    else if (num > root->data)
        root->right = delete(num,root->right,n);
    else
    {
        //found you
        //Case1:Leaf
        if(root->right==NULL&&root->left==NULL){
        free(root);
        root=NULL;
    }
    //Case2:One Child
    //left Child
    if(root->right==NULL&&root->left!=NULL){
        struct node * temp;
        temp=presearch(num,origin);
        //On the Left
        if(temp->left){
            temp->left=root->left;
            return origin;
        }
        //On the Right
        if(temp->right){
            temp->right=root->left;
            return origin;
        }
    }
    //right Child
    if(root->right!=NULL&&root->left==NULL){
        struct node * temp;
        temp=presearch(num,root);
        //On the Left
        if(temp->left->data=root->data){
            temp->left=root->right;
            return origin;
        }
        //On the Right
        if(temp->right->data=root->data){
            temp->right=root->right;
            return origin;
        }
    }
    //Case3: Two Children
    return p;
    }
}
```

And I called the function like this(root is the root of the tree):

```
struct node *o;
o=delete(15,root,root);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How was the tree created? How were the nodes inserted? How was the `delete` function called. We need complete (yet minimum) code to be able to fully answer your question

Comment: @kaylum thanks for the reminder, I have edited the question

Comment: In case of `(num < root->data)` and `(num > root->data)`, the function `delete()` perform a recursive call `root-><xx> = delete(num,root-><xx>,n);`, but doesn't return a `struct node *` value. Please enable warnings of your compiler and remove that error.

Comment: In `// Case1:Leaf`, after freeing the root node `free(root);`, instead of assigning `root=NULL;` which occurs an error on the following if-condition `if(root->right==NULL&&root->left!=NULL)`, it is necessary to add `return (NULL);`.

Comment: Thank you! I fix my code according to your suggestion, but my pointer still change after returned and I don't know if it's because the way I return it or something else

Comment: never mind, its the recursive calls that changed my pointer, thank you!

Comment: Maybe the following if-conditions are not the expected ones `if(temp->left->data=root->data)` and `if(temp->right->data=root->data)`. It should be equal operator `==` instead of equal assignment `=`.